# MongoDB: how to store GPS track including timestamps

Tags: mongodb, gps

I'm interested in your input on what's the most efficient (or most intelligent) way to store a GPS track consisting of GPS coordinates (Longitude & Latitude) and timestamps.

I'm thinking of those two ideas:

```
gpsTrack = {   
       "gps_track" : {   
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [
              { "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [104.0, 0.3]},
                "properties": {
                    "absolute_timestamp" : "2011-12-31T23:50:59Z" 
                } 
              },

            { "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [128.0, 0.5]},
                "properties": {
                    "absolute_timestamp" : "2011-12-31T23:59:59Z" 
                } 
              }
            ] }
}
```

Or using the GeoJSON MultiPoint and the timestamps as an array.

```
gpsTrack = {   
        "geometry": {"type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [[104.0, 0.3], [128.0, 0.5]]},
        "properties": {
            "timestamps" : ["2011-12-31T23:50:59Z", "2011-12-31T23:59:59Z"]
}
```

The total amount of way points is assumed to be 4.000 to 10.000 but for sure below 100.000. For the first idea I'm afraid that the collection will become quite long since every points and its timestamp is stored separately. While the second idea is more compact and utilizing the MultiPoint GeoJSON type.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Isn't [LineString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#linestring) a better fit then `MultiPoint` for a track data?

Comment: Might be, but then you can't do any Geo-spatial query in MongoDB. But I'm more interested in how to join it with the timestamps.

Comment: LineString is also supported by mongodb geo queries. Beside of lineString or MultiPoint, for timestamp part; what if you put time stamp inside coordinate sub arrays as a third element? I didn't try it but most likely mongodb will just ignore it for geo queries but you can use it and there will be no need for matching coordinates array and timestamp array

Comment: I didn't get the timestamp part. Can you post an answer with an example MongoDB structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use coordinates array for timestamp too. Most likely mongodb will just interested in first 2 objects of coordinates. You can put timestamp as third object.

```
gpsTrack = {   
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPoint", 
        "coordinates": [
          [104.0, 0.3, "2011-12-31T23:50:59Z"], 
          [128.0, 0.5, "2011-12-31T23:59:59Z"]]
    }
}
```

like I said, I didn't try if this violates mongodb to make geo query over `coordinates`.

Comment: Insertion, Index creation and Querying worked fine. Didn't know that you can add fields to existing datatypes like a Point or MultiPoint. I will wait for other idea before accepting a solution. Thx!